# Issues with syntax c#, unable to use ojects/call get, set,

Tags: c#, list, object, syntax-error

I am new to C# and have been working on a project for a maze game in a haunted house context.After researching different approaches I have decided to go with using objects and a linked list. However, despite weeks of trying I am struggling with the code and have gotten to the point after hours of reading articles and watching online tutorials that I am now more confused that ever before. I want to go with this approach rather than an array as I feel like this is more efficient and more OOP. 
I was thinking of going with a simple if/else structure but for this level of coding I feel it would be too messy. 
Any help, constructive criticism or ideas would be highly appreciated as I don't want to give up after so many hours spent on it but I feel its getting to that point. This is my code so far.
Thanks in advance :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace maze_3
{//open namespace
    class Room
    {//open class room

        private string RoomName;
        private Room N = null; // so that when i set the links they are automatically null unless i specify in main 
        private Room E = null;
        private Room S = null;
        private Room W = null;

        public Room X { get; private set; } // the software implemented this 

        public void setName(string N) // so that i am able to set the name of the room
        {
            RoomName = N;
        }

        public void setN(Room X) // sets the north direction between the objects of the rooms
        {
            N = X;
        }

        public void setE(Room X)
        {
            E = X;
        }

        public void setW(Room X)
        {
            W = X;
        }

        public void setS(Room x)
        {
            S = X;
        }   

        public Room getN() // want to get a direction from the user, in this case they would input a north direction 
        {
            return N;
        }

        public Room getE()
        {
            return E;
        }

        public Room getS()
        {
            return S;
        }

        public Room getW()
        {
            return W;
        }      

    static void Main(string[] args)// it is asking for a ; here but also says that I should declare it as extern, partial etc

    class chamber// its telling me that a ; is expected ???
    {//open class chamber

        chamber gh = new chamber();// my objects that are the rooms in the haunted house. 
        chamber kit = new chamber();
        chamber Pan = new chamber();
        chamber Dun = new chamber();
        chamber dr = new chamber();
        chamber lib = new chamber();
        chamber din = new chamber();
        chamber sr = new chamber();
        chamber weap = new chamber();
        chamber tow = new chamber();
        chamber gal = new chamber();
        chamber tr = new chamber();

        gh.RoomName("Great Hall"); //to set the object name as the Great Hall, all get and set links were available in class
            gh.setW(dr); ///I want to set a west direction between my object gh to dr
            gh.SetS(kit);// to set a south link between my two objects 

            dr.setName("Drawing Room");//states that all my setlinks are not valid in the current context- this is for all
            dr.setS(lib); //it states the ; is not a valid token in class, struct or interface

            kit.setName("Kitchen");// it states that my objects e.g kit is not valid in this current context-this is for all
            kit.setS(pan);

            pan.setName("Pantry");
            pan.SetE(dun); /// this is a dead end in the game 

            lib.setName("Library ");
            lib.setE(din);

            din.setName("Dining Room");
            din.setN(sr);
            din.setE(gal);
            din.setS(weap); //dead end in the game

            sr.setName("Smoking Room");
            sr.setE(tow);//dead end

            gal.setName("Treasure Room");
            gal.setS(tr)    

            /// </summary> so i wanted to have the actual game play to follow a linked list with a if else structure. 
            int finish = 0;
        string choice;    
        Room current;

        current=gh; 
            while (finish !=1) (finish ==0) //im confused as to which condition is best to use. 
            {Console.WriteLine("You are in room " + current.getRoomname() + "and you can move ");
           if( current.getN() != null)
           Console.WriteLine("North (N) ");
          if( current.getE() != null)
           Console.WriteLine("East (E) ");

         Console.WriteLine("Please enter the direction you wish to go in ");
         string choice = Console.ReadLine();
         if (choice[0] == 'E') // or alternative means of getting in a choice from a string
        current = current.getE();// to be able to move to next 'current'room

            // i was going to do this for all the options. 

        if(current == tr // ie last room
            exit = 1;
        Console.Writeline ("Well done you have found the treasure room");              
        }//close chamber

        }//close class rooom

    } //close namespace
```

Comment: can you explain your issues more? i didn't understand your problem.

Comment: I think it is getting messed with the class definitions, check the `}//close chamber`followed the `}//close class rooom`and the `} //close namespace`

Comment: sorry for not being clear. Firstly, I am stuck as I have successfully created my objects but then am unable to use them in conjunction with the set methods in Main, and likewise with the set methods. I think this related to the next problem as to why my syntax is not working when I am setting the game play, i.e console.writeline you are in ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a class object which doesn't have a main().  A project only has one main.  So you either need to make the Room the main() in the application or removed main method from the Room Class.  See my code below for changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace maze_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Room home = new Room("White House");
            home.CreateRoom("W", "West Wing");
        }
    }
    class Room
    {//open class room

        private string RoomName;
        private Room N = null; // so that when i set the links they are automatically null unless i specify in main 
        private Room E = null;
        private Room S = null;
        private Room W = null;
        private List<Chamber> chambers = new List<Chamber>();

        public Room() { }
        public Room(string name)
        {
            this.RoomName = name;
        }
        public void CreateRoom(string direction, string name)
        {
            Room newRoom = new Room();
            newRoom.RoomName = name;
            switch (direction)
            {
                case "N":
                    N = newRoom;
                    break;
                case "E":
                    E = newRoom;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    S = newRoom;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    W = newRoom;
                    break;

            }
        }


    }//close class rooom


    public class Chamber// its telling me that a ; is expected ???
    {//open class chamber
        string name = "";
    }//close chamber
}
```

Comment: so is the syntax: Room newRoom =  new Room();  the same as when I created my objects and if so where I do set the name- 'string name = ""' ? Also will this replace the if else structure I have or does this slot in where I have the current objects. Thanks

Comment: I updated the code to include main and changed code so new rooms are connected to parent.  The switch statement will replace your 'IF".  The constructor will set the RoomName